# フッターに表示されている「当社に応募」が不自然

Tags: 討議

「採用情報」と書いておくのが日本語のサイトとしては無難かと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的な問題は応募サイトは100％英語になっています。それは問題なかったら、「採用情報」に変換しました。

Comment: 「当社に応募」よりも良いですね！
ただ「当社で働く」でも良いですが、助詞（て、に、を、は、が、など）が入ると少し不自然な気もします。理想的には「助詞を使わない名詞」で表現できるのがベストです。

Comment: 「採用情報」が無難だと思いますが、その場合SE社が主語なんですよね。"work here"のように応募者を主語とした言い方であれば、短く「働きたい」はどうでしょう

Comment: @JunichiIto 「採用情報」にしました。